# A variable not detected as not used

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, gcc-warning

I am using g++ 4.3.0 to compile this example :

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector< int > a;
  int b;
}
```

If I compile the example with maximum warning level, I get a warning that the variable **b** is not used :

```
[vladimir@juniper data_create]$ g++ m.cpp -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic
m.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
m.cpp:7: warning: unused variable ‘b’
[vladimir@juniper data_create]$
```

The question is : why the variable **a** is not reported as not used?
What parameters do I have to pass to get the warning for the variable **a**?

Comment: Some GCC code analysis warnings only work (or work better) if you use optimization too, try with -O2 or -O3

Comment: @Laurynas Biveinis I think the answers are correct. The optimization level plays no role in this case (to be sure I tried).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In theory, the default constructor for `std::vector<int>` could have arbitrary side effects, so the compiler cannot figure out whether removing the definition of `a` would change the semantics of the program. You only get those warning for built-in types.

A better example is a lock:

```
{
    lock a;
    // ...
    // do critical stuff
    // a is never used here
    // ...
    // lock is automatically released by a's destructor (RAII)
}
```

Even though `a` is never used after its definition, removing the first line would be wrong.

Comment: Excellent answer / example.  I used a similar example a while ago when explaining the same concept to a client.  Client fought me tooth & nail, arguing that "lock a" would be optimized away since it "wasn't used".  I explained that it was guaranteed not to be eliminated (side effects of constructor/destructor - mutex acquisition/release).  As I recall, I finally had to find chapter & verse in the standard which supported my point.  Will try to find & post back.

Answer (score 2):

a is actually used after it is declared as its destructor gets called at the end of its scope.

Answer (score 1):

a is not a built-in type. You are actually calling the constructor of `std::vector<int>` and assigning the result to a. The compiler sees this as usage because the constructor could have side effects.